# Quicklook for fullscreen terminal

Tags: terminal, quicklook

I recently realized you can use quicklook from the command line. Here's the example: `qlmanage -p somefile.txt >& /dev/null &` When this command is invoked quicklook opens its popup *in a different desktop*.

What I'd like is for quicklook to open in the *same* desktop window as full-screened terminal (just above it). Is this possible with quicklook?

Comment: The answer appears to be "no" as windows can't generally appear on top of full-screened applications.  But thanks for the tip about qlmanage!